# Is it possible to get a list of all shortcuts in a Qt/C++ app?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, shortcut

I would like to provide my users with a cheat sheet of shortcuts they can use when running my app. However, I wouldn't want this list to become outdated over time, so preferably this would be something we compute automatically. Is this possible at all?

Comment: how about leveraging `findChildren<QShortcut*>()`?

Comment: Thanks @tinkertime, that's what I have in mind right now.

Comment: Did you find any better solution that findChilden?

Comment: @tinkertime Doesn't seem to work when you have shortcuts defined in UI form files and plugins.